# Does OMDB Api Retrieve information from IMDB

Tags: api, imdb

My Question is Does **OMDB Api** Retrieve information from **IMDB**.
or OMDB has its own database and can not fetch movies information from IMDB.
Please Answer me if any have confirm info about it.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like they have their own DB. When we traceroute OMDB goes for

```
*   *   *


2   core21.hetzner.de   213.239.229.129 de  0.244 ms    0.258 ms    0.253 ms


3   core11.hetzner.de   213.239.245.221 de  2.917 ms    2.913 ms    2.908 ms


4   juniper4.ffm.hetzner.de 213.239.245.10  de  4.916 ms    4.923 ms     
juniper5.rz2.hetzner.de 213.239.229.166 de  2.848 ms


5   ae1-710.fra20.core-backbone.com 80.255.15.121   de  5.050 ms    6.720 ms    5.044 ms


6   ae1-2081.sth10.core-backbone.com    80.255.14.194   de  22.998 ms   22.506 ms   22.948 ms


7               *   *   *


8               *   *   *


9               *   *   *
```

and IMDB goes for

```
1               *   *   *


2   core21.hetzner.de   213.239.229.129 de  0.282 ms    0.271 ms    0.261 ms


3   core1.hetzner.de    213.239.245.218 de  4.876 ms         
core1.hetzner.de    213.239.245.177 de  4.875 ms    4.865 ms


4   cloudflare.fra.ecix.net 62.69.146.42    de  5.082 ms    5.077 ms    5.066 ms


5               *   *   *
```